# TIFF to PDF conversion in Rails using ImageMagick/MiniMagick on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, imagemagick, minimagick

I am attempting to use the mini_magick GEM to convert TIFF files to PDF in Rails 4.2.6. The conversions work when testing in development but in production on the Heroku cedar-14 stack, they produce errors like the following:

```
convert /tmp/mini_magick20181121-5-11mxfxh /tmp/mini_magick20181121-5-6e3jp2.pdf` failed with error: 
convert.im6: memory allocation failed `/tmp/mini_magick20181121-5-11mxfxh' @ error/tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1268. 
convert.im6: no images defined `/tmp/mini_magick20181121-5-6e3jp2.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/304
```

ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-09-28 Q16

Features: OpenMP

GEM: mini_magick 4.9.2

Rails 4.2.6

UPDATE: The production server has TOO MUCH memory. When I run it with a 2.5 GB dyno, it fails. When I run it with a 1 GB dyno it works. I have duplicated this on the stage server as well. Increasing server memory causes it to fail with memory errors (very backwards!). I have tried adding environment variables MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT and MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT but they don't seem to have an effect. Also tried passing in `-limit memory 200MB -limit map 200MB` on the command line to no effect.

Comment: Please show all of the `convert -version` information, including the Delegates to be sure you have TIFF installed. How big is your tiff file? It would appear from the message (memory allocation failed)  that you ran out of memory or temp space. What is your RAM allocation? `convert -list resource` should show all your resources.

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-09-28 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (c) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

Comment: convert -list format includes "TIFF* rw+" and "TIFF64* rw-", LIBTIFF Version 4.0.3 ********* convert -list configure also includes "tiff" on the DELEGATES line

Comment: How big is your file? Also note that Linux distributions show old versions number, but the patch date is more important. However, often they only patch for security issues and not all the bug fixes or enhancements. So if your identify shows tiff listed as delegates and your version is 4.0.3 you might try upgrading libtiff to the current version. I am using 4.0.9. Otherwise it would seem to be either a resource issue or a bug in ImageMagick

Comment: CONTINUED: Does it work with a smaller TIFF file? Does it work converting a PNG or JPG file to PDF? Does it work in the command line rather than through mini-magics?

Comment: The odd thing is that conversions work on Heroku on our stage server from both the Rails web and the Rails console. They work on production in the Rails console. But they do not work in production from the Rails web. Everything matches between the servers. They use the same slug and the same stack.

Comment: Perhaps you have differences in either the ENVIRONMENT variables for your server or for Imagemagick. Or you have different policy.xml files for Imagemagick. You can check your resource limits with `convert -list resource`.

Comment: I figured out the problem in a repeatable way. But the solutions don't work. Here is the issue: the production server has TOO MUCH memory. When I run it with a 2.5 GB dyno, it fails. When I run it with a 1 GB dyno it works. I have duplicated this on the stage server as well. Increasing server memory causes it to fail with memory errors (very backwards!). I have tried adding environment variables MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT and MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT but they don't seem to have an effect. Also tried passing in `-limit memory 200MB -limit map 200MB` on the command line to no effect.